# How to get a Docker container to see ROS traffic from the local host?

Tags: ros, python, docker, jackal

I am trying to get ROS traffic from the local host to a Docker container on that same host but I get an error when I run my Docker container.

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ros:noetic
ARG ROS_APP_CFG=ros_app.cfg
LABEL developer=jason@myemail.io

RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install python3-pip

RUN pip install --no-binary protobuf protobuf && \
    pip install pyzmq

RUN mkdir -p /opt/my_server

COPY ./config-python /opt/my_server/config-python

RUN cd /opt/my_server/config-python && \
    pip install .

EXPOSE 11311/udp

COPY src/${ROS_APP_CFG} /ros_app.cfg
COPY src/ros_app.py /

WORKDIR /

CMD ["python3", "ros_app.py"]
```

The Docker build and run commands are:

```
docker image build --build-arg="ROS_APP_CFG=jakal_sub.cfg" -t jakal_sub:1.0.0 -f Dockerfile_sub .

docker container run --rm --name jakal-ros-sub -e ROS_MASTER_URI=http://0.0.0.0:11311 -p 11311:11311 jakal_sub:1.0.0
```

I run `roscore` on my local host. The port is 11311. The error message is:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jakal-ros-sub (7d200e24af39943cad71874c08a3e4ee63a22b8ade479a753f87ce0f9d3a86b3): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:11311: bind: address already in use.
```

I assume it refers to the ROS master; but how do I get the Docker container to see the ROS traffic?

Comment: This is a common problem. See the gist I wrote on this a few years ago anmd look at the troubleshooting at the bottom: https://gist.github.com/chfritz/8c2adab45a94e091be77c55b0432ad2e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I use `--network` host in the command.

```
docker container run --rm --name jakal-ros-sub -e ROS_MASTER_URI=http://0.0.0.0:11311 --network host jakal_sub:1.0.0
```